# Not all of the content showing inside of the popup

Tags: php, jquery, function, bpopup

I have a popup plugin. Whenever i click the link, the things inside element_to_pop_up DIV are written in the popup window. However i added a function which is not appearing in the popup, it is showed outside of it in the main page. Why does that happen?
I guess that the dots make this function get echoed but they are out of the element to pop up DIV. How to get over it?

```
function writecomments($photoid){
echo $photoid;
}

echo "
<div class='element_to_pop_up'>
".writecomments($photoid)."
<img id='stop' src='".$numphotos['link']."' alt='photo' class='photolink' align='middle'>
<form action='main.php' class='commentsform' method='post'>
<textarea rows='8' cols='80' name='comments'></textarea> <br />
<input type='hidden' name='pid' value='".$photoid."'>
<input type='submit' name='send' value='Wyślij'>
</form>
<a class='b-close'></a>
</div>";

}
```

I am using bpopup plugin

```
http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/
```

Source code:

```
<div class='element_to_pop_up'>
writecomments(302)
<img id='stop' src='upload/Dzuliet_3.jpg' alt='photo' class='photolink' align='middle'>
<form action='main.php' class='commentsform' method='post'>
<textarea rows='8' cols='80' name='comments'></textarea> <br />
<input type='hidden' name='pid' value='302'>
<input type='submit' name='send' value='Wyślij'>
</form>
<a class='b-close'></a>
```

Comment: Can you provide rendered HTML markup? `However i added a function which is not appearing in the popup` Which function are you talking about???

Comment: I am talking about writecomments function. I am not sure what you mean by the rendered markup. Actually everything is inside the popup but the writecomments function appears outside of it.

Comment: The rendered HTML markup as it apperas on client side, not this *unreadable* server side code. And so, is `$photoid` a simple string?  Maybe this is a simple PHP issue, i hate so much it

Comment: Poopups are bad, noone wants a poopup.

Comment: @A.Wolff I have edited my question adding a source code part of it

Comment: This isn't the HTML markup as it appears on browser i guess

Comment: @adeneo Actually people like nice looking popups to see the content of clicked link instead of redirecting on another page etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201662/when-not-to-use-pop-ups

Comment: @adeneo Yes but they are talking about the bad popups. My popups are good ones :D Lets say you click on my nick to see more information about me. Instead of directing to another page i offer the clear info in small popup window. This is much more comfortable

Comment: There are no good poopup, they are all annoying !

Comment: But I think what you mean is a modal, not a poopup, which in some cases are OK.

Comment: @adeneo yes this is modal, i am kinda new in these things so i named it wrong

Answer (score 0):

To do it correctly it is needed to use return instead of echo

```
function writecomments($photoid){
return $photoid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't echo,just return it :)

```
function writecomments($photoid){
 return $photoid;
}
```