# call to function query on non object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

This function returns only one row from database while there are many of them.
Could someone tell me why please? Can i do this other way?

```
function writecomments($photoid){
include 'connect.php';
$stmt = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE photoid = '".$photoid."' ");
while($row = $stmt -> fetch()) {
return $row['comment'];
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

I have also tried this way:

```
function writecomments($photoid){
include 'connect.php';
$stmt = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE photoid = '".$photoid."' ");
while($row = $stmt -> fetch()) {
$allcomments = $allcomments . " " . $row['comment'];
}
return $allcomments;
$stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

Comment: note that having the return before the closeCursor() means, that the cursor is never closed

Comment: your second attempt is close to the correct way. How about debugging, and try echoing $allcomments, or even $row['comment'] within the loop and see if you're actually getting the results you think you should?

Comment: How can do that without comments table schema and more info?

Comment: @ElefantPhace My second option makes my code not work at all :P
I actually have tried to echo it but in my case i cant do this.

Comment: @QMaster I have a table "comments" containing columns "id" "photoid" "comment". In addition the table is not empty

Comment: care to elaborate on that? Why can't you echo? that makes no sense

Comment: @ElefantPhace It is highly connected with my last asked question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668779/not-all-of-the-content-showing-inside-of-the-popup

Comment: "call to function query on non object" is this the error you're getting? Please update your question with all relevant code and errors you're getting. like what exactly is `$pdo` ?

Comment: @LetMeLearn123, yeah I'm not even going to bother with that. For testing/debugging purposes, you CAN echo whatever and wherever you want and need to to see if you're getting the correct response. Forget about whatever you're trying to do and just call the function with a photoid and echo the results within the while loop to see if you're getting what you need. But first, look at my other comment above.

Comment: @ElefantPhace The echo is working great. Anyways as i figured out in my last question. I cant use echo because it makes my string go out of the popup div and it does not popup in a modal box

Comment: yeah maybe, but that's not important when your DEBUGGING to find the problem with your code. Quit thinking about the look and layout. this is simply for debugging purposes.

Comment: @LetMeLearn123 Thanks, but I said that for caring for the future about writing anythings may need in question. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming $pdo is a PDO connection object. In which case it could be to do with the fact you are using PDO::query - which is a bit of a tricky function - and how  you are iterating through the result set.
###If you want to use the PDO `query` method then it should be within a foreach loop.
From the [PDO query official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)
PDO::query() executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the result set (if any) returned by the statement as a PDOStatement object.

> If you do not fetch all of the data in a result set before issuing
> your next call to PDO::query(), your call may fail.

I would try:

```
function writecomments($photoid){
include 'connect.php';

    foreach ($pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE photoid = '".$photoid."' ") as $row) {
   
        return $row['comment'];

    }
    
$stmt->closeCursor();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- That's what `fetch()` does it returns the next row from the result
  set. If you need all rows you will need to manually append them to an array, or use `fetchAll()` instead in order to get all rows at once.
- It looks a little weird to have an include inside of the function, should be passed as parameter or maybe create the connection in the function.
- Use prepared statements for this query.

---

I would do it this way:
**Function:**

```
function writecomments($pdo, $photoid){
    $sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM comments 
        WHERE photoid = ?
    ";
    $stmt = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($photoid));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    //return all rows
    return $rows;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
include 'connect.php';
$rows = writecomments($pdo, $photoid);
var_dump($rows);
```